# error in line: from builtins import True added by autocompletion

Tags: python-3.7, pydev

I am experiencing the following strange and annoying behavior of PyDev plugin when entering source code: when typing the beginning letters of some reserved keywords, as `Tru` or `Fal`, PyDev auto-completion mecanism randomly only suggests in its popup "True-builtins", which correctly completes `Tru` with `True`, BUT ADDS `from builtins import True` at the beginning (which yields an error). Some other times, completion works normally: only `True` (alone, without -builtins) is proposed in the popup; in this case, typing ENTER completes with `True` AND doesn't add `from builtins import True` at the beginning.

I suspect this comes from bad configuration of PyDev (not sure), but I cannot fix it though I searched in window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Analysis->Code completion (and elsewhere). Also I searched in stack overflow pydev quesios tagged PyDev and googling did not either give valuable hints.

If anyone has an idea, thank's in advance. Hereunder are my version informations:

PyDev version: 8.0.1.202011071328

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200
OS: Linux, v.4.19.0-12-amd64, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.5
Java version: 12.0.2

Greatfully,

Frédéric Baldit.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot when that happens (although it lists some `True` definitions from other places depending on how the completion was asked, it doesn't provide one from `builtins` and the first entry is always correct... I suspect this comes from some compatibility library -- potentially `python-future`?)

Comment: Hi, here are jpg screenshots showing what I said: [img1](https://ibb.co/0Y7cQM0)  [img2](https://ibb.co/99b4ZFR)
[img3](https://ibb.co/XYykq94)
[img4](https://ibb.co/9p6ty6J). Don't hesitate to ask more information about my config., especially concerning python install.

Comment: Ok, so, which Python version are you using? Which libraries do you have installed in your env? If you run the following code: `import builtins;print(builtins)` what's the output?

Comment: I'm using python3.7. The output of pip list is: [here](http://paste.debian.net/1172527/) In PyDev config I see that the following libraries path are used: /usr/lib/python3.7    /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload      /home/fred/.local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages and /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages. Finally, the output of the print(builtins) command is: <module 'builtins' (built-in)>

Comment: Actually, I've been able to reproduce it with Python 3.7 on Linux. I created https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/1117 to track it.